# SDL_types.h file not found using xcode

Tags: xcode, sdl

Getting this error when trying to use SDL_mixer on xcode 4.6...

SDL_types.h file not found.. in the SDL_mixer.h file

I am including all the correct files as far as I can tell and have included the frameworks (both SDL and SDL_mixer) to my /systems/library/frameworks folder and it compiles well until I add SDL_mixer.h to my project. What should I do?

Here is main.cpp

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include "SDLMain.h"
#include "SDL_mixer.h"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    Mix_Chunk song;
    //Initialize SDL_mixer
    if( Mix_OpenAudio( 22050, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 4096 ) == -1 )
    {
        return false;
    }

    song = Mix_LoadWAV("song.wav");
    SDL_SetVideoMode(1000, 500, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
    SDL_Event event;
    bool done = false;
    while(!done)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                done = true;
            }
            if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
            {
                if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_UP)
                {
                    Mix_PlayChannel( -1, song, 0 );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check your header files and how you link them.

Comment: Try including <SDL_mixer/SDL_mixer.h> instead of just "SDL_mixer.h"